# How do i encrypt with Java/BouncyCastle and decrypt with eg. OpenSSL

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle

I'm experimenting with BouncyCastle to encrypt a string or file and then decrypt it with the openssl command line tool.

I have done the encryption like this

```
String text = "Asdf";

String encryptedText;
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";

byte[] keyBytes = "0123456789abcdef".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
secureRandom.nextBytes(ivBytes);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);

byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
encryptedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext);
```

and the string I get after encryptions is

```
fH/ybmlsrqaj1jVsjJEyBg==
```

I have saved this in a file
and then I try to decrypt it with this command:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -K 30313233343536373839616263646566 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -nopad  -base64 -in in.txt -out decrypted.tx
```

There is no errors, but I get an empty file.

Is this not possible or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without any specific knowledge of both tools, I see "PKCS7Padding" in Java and "-nopad" in openssl, is this normal?

Comment: I dont know - but if i dont put this parameter i get following error : 
bad decrypt
80A08A0602000000:error:1C80006B:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_generic_block_final:wrong final block length:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon.c:429:

Comment: Remove `-nopad`, add `-A`.

Comment: Thanks a million. So simple but -A is working. How do i set your answer as correct ?